# Message is not consumed by all consumers when network brokers is configured in ActiveMQ

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I have 2 instances of my application on the same machine (although it could be on different machines as well) with two Tomcat instances with different ports and Apache ActiveMQ is embedded in the application.

I have configured a static network of brokers so that the message from one instance can be consumed by all  other instance as well (each instance can be producer and consumer).

servlet:

```
package com.activemq.servlet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.activemq.ActiveMQStartup;
import com.activemq.MQPublisher;
import com.activemq.SendMsg;
import com.activemq.SendMsgToAllInstance;
import com.activemq.TestPublisher;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ActiveMQStartUpServlet
 */
@WebServlet(value = "/activeMQStartUpServlet", loadOnStartup = 1)
public class ActiveMQStartUpServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ActiveMQStartup mqStartup = null;
    private static final Map pooledPublishers = new HashMap();

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        System.out.println("starting servelt--------------");
        super.init(config);
        //Apache Active MQ Startup
        mqStartup = new ActiveMQStartup();
        mqStartup.startBrokerService();

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(req.getParameter("distributedMsg"));
        String mqConfig = null;
        String distributedMsg = req.getParameter("distributedMsg");
        String simpleMsg = req.getParameter("simpleMsg");
        if (distributedMsg != null && !distributedMsg.equals(""))
            mqConfig = "distributedMsg";
        else if (simpleMsg != null && !simpleMsg.equals(""))
            mqConfig = "simpleMsg";
        MQPublisher publisher = acquirePublisher(mqConfig);
        try {
            publisher.publish(mqConfig);
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            releasePublisher(publisher);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void releasePublisher(MQPublisher publisher) {
        if (publisher == null) return;
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        LinkedList publishers;
        TestPublisher poolablePublisher = (TestPublisher)publisher;
        publishers = getPooledPublishers(poolablePublisher.getConfigurationName());
        synchronized (publishers) {
            publishers.addLast(poolablePublisher);
        }

    }

    private MQPublisher acquirePublisher(String mqConfig) {
        LinkedList publishers = getPooledPublishers(mqConfig);
        MQPublisher publisher = getMQPubliser(publishers);
        if (publisher != null) return publisher;
        try {
            if (mqConfig.equals("distributedMsg"))
                return new TestPublisher(MQConfiguration.getConfiguration("distributedMsg"), new SendMsgToAllInstance());
            else    
                return new TestPublisher(MQConfiguration.getConfiguration("simpleMsg"), new SendMsg());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private LinkedList getPooledPublishers(String mqConfig) {
         LinkedList publishers = null;
         publishers = (LinkedList) pooledPublishers.get(mqConfig);
         if (publishers == null) {
             synchronized(pooledPublishers) {
                 publishers = (LinkedList) pooledPublishers.get(mqConfig);
                 if (publishers == null) {
                     publishers = new LinkedList();
                     pooledPublishers.put(mqConfig, publishers);
                 }
             }
         }
        return publishers;
    }

    private MQPublisher getMQPubliser(LinkedList publishers) {
        synchronized (publishers) {
            while (!publishers.isEmpty()) {
                TestPublisher publisher = (TestPublisher)publishers.removeFirst();
                return publisher;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }




}
```

Configuration:

```
package com.activemq.servlet;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicConnection;
import javax.jms.TopicConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

import com.activemq.ActiveMQContext;

public class MQConfiguration {
    private static final Map configurations = new HashMap();
    private String mqConfig;
    private String topicName;
    private TopicConnection topicConnection = null;

    private MQConfiguration(String mqConfig, String string, String string2) {
        this.mqConfig = mqConfig;

        try {
            String topicFactoryConName = ActiveMQContext.getProperty(mqConfig);
            this.topicName = (mqConfig.equals("distributedMsg") ? ActiveMQContext.getProperty("distributedTopic"):ActiveMQContext.getProperty("normalTopic"));
            TopicConnectionFactory factory = (ActiveMQConnectionFactory) ActiveMQContext.getContext()
                    .lookup(topicFactoryConName);
            this.topicConnection = factory.createTopicConnection();
            this.topicConnection.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public static MQConfiguration getConfiguration(String mqConfig) {
        if (mqConfig == null || "".equals(mqConfig)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("mqConfig is null or empty");
        }

        MQConfiguration config = null;

        if (config != null) {
            return config;
        }
        synchronized (configurations) {
            config = (MQConfiguration) configurations.get(mqConfig);
            if (config == null) {
                config = new MQConfiguration(mqConfig, "userName", "userPassword");
            }
            configurations.put(mqConfig, config);
        }

        return config;
    }

    public String getMqConfig() {
        return this.mqConfig;
    }

    public TopicSession createTopicSession(boolean isTransacted, int autoAcknowledge) throws JMSException {
        if (this.topicConnection == null) {
            IllegalStateException ise = new IllegalStateException("topic connection not configured");
            throw ise;
        }
        return this.topicConnection.createTopicSession(isTransacted, autoAcknowledge);
    }

    public Topic getTopic() {
        try {
            return (Topic) ActiveMQContext.getContext().lookup(this.topicName);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

publisher:

```
package com.activemq;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.jms.Topic;
import javax.jms.TopicPublisher;
import javax.jms.TopicSession;

import com.activemq.servlet.MQConfiguration;

public class TestPublisher implements MQPublisher {
    private final String configurationName;
    private TopicSession topicSession = null;
    private TopicPublisher topicPublisher = null;

    public TestPublisher(MQConfiguration config, Object messageListener) throws JMSException {
        if (config == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("config == null");
        }
        Topic topic = config.getTopic();
        this.configurationName = config.getMqConfig();
        this.topicSession = config.createTopicSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        this.topicPublisher = this.topicSession.createPublisher(topic);
        MessageConsumer msgConsumer = this.topicSession.createConsumer(topic);
        msgConsumer.setMessageListener((MessageListener) messageListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void publish(String msg) throws JMSException {
        this.topicPublisher.publish(createMessage(msg, this.topicSession));
    }

    private Message createMessage(String msg, Session session) throws JMSException {
        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(msg);
        return message;
    }

    public String getConfigurationName() {
        return this.configurationName;
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```
package com.activemq;

import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;

public class SendMsgToAllInstance implements MessageListener {

    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        System.out.println("distributed message-------------");

        // We have call to dao layer to to fetch some data and cached it

    }

}
```

JNDI:activemq-jndi.properties

```
# JNDI properties file to setup the JNDI server within ActiveMQ

#
# Default JNDI properties settings
#
java.naming.factory.initial=org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
java.naming.provider.url=tcp://localhost:61616
activemq.network.connector=static:(tcp://localhost:61620)

#activemq.network.connector=broker:(tcp://localhost:61619,network:static:tcp://localhost:61620)?persistent=false&useJmx=true
activemq.data.directory=data61619
activemq.jmx.port=1099

#
# Set the connection factory name(s) as well as the destination names. The connection factory name(s)
# as well as the second part (after the dot) of the left hand side of the destination definition
# must be used in the JNDI lookups.
#
connectionFactoryNames = distributedMsgFactory,simpleMsgFactory
topic.jms/distributedTopic=distributedTopic
topic.jms/normalTopic=normalTopic

distributedMsg=distributedMsgFactory
simpleMsg=simpleMsgFactory

distributedTopic=jms/distributedTopic
normalTopic=jms/normalTopic
```

**ActiveMQStartup**:

```
package com.activemq;

import java.net.URI;

import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerPlugin;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector;
import org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.ManagementContext;
import org.apache.activemq.network.NetworkConnector;
import org.apache.activemq.security.JaasAuthenticationPlugin;

public class ActiveMQStartup {
    private final String bindAddress;
    private final String dataDirectory;
    private BrokerService broker = new BrokerService();
    protected final int numRestarts = 3;
    protected final int networkTTL = 2;
    protected final int consumerTTL = 2;
    protected final boolean dynamicOnly = true;
    protected final String networkBroker;
    protected final String jmxPort;

    public ActiveMQStartup() {
        ActiveMQContext context = new ActiveMQContext();
        context.loadJndiProperties();
        bindAddress = ActiveMQContext.getProperty("java.naming.provider.url");
        dataDirectory = ActiveMQContext.getProperty("activemq.data.directory");
        networkBroker = ActiveMQContext.getProperty("activemq.network.connector");
        jmxPort = ActiveMQContext.getProperty("activemq.jmx.port");
    }

    // Start activemq broker service
    public void startBrokerService() {
        try {
            broker.setDataDirectory("../" + dataDirectory);
            broker.setBrokerName(dataDirectory);
            broker.setUseShutdownHook(true);
            TransportConnector connector = new TransportConnector();
            connector.setUri(new URI(bindAddress));         

            //broker.setPlugins(new BrokerPlugin[]{new JaasAuthenticationPlugin()});
            ManagementContext mgContext = new ManagementContext();
            if (networkBroker != null && !networkBroker.isEmpty()) {
                NetworkConnector networkConnector = broker.addNetworkConnector(networkBroker);
                networkConnector.setName(dataDirectory);
                mgContext.setConnectorPort(Integer.parseInt(jmxPort));
                broker.setManagementContext(mgContext);
                configureNetworkConnector(networkConnector);
            }
            broker.setNetworkConnectorStartAsync(true);
            broker.addConnector(connector);
            broker.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to start Apache MQ Broker : " + e);
        }
    }

    private void configureNetworkConnector(NetworkConnector networkConnector) {
        networkConnector.setDuplex(true);
        networkConnector.setNetworkTTL(networkTTL);
        networkConnector.setDynamicOnly(dynamicOnly);
        networkConnector.setConsumerTTL(consumerTTL);
        //networkConnector.setStaticBridge(true);
    }

    // Stop broker service
    public void stopBrokerService() {
        try {
            broker.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to stop the ApacheMQ Broker service " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am starting the tomcat instance one by one and seeing the network connection between the broker is getting established.

When I am sending messge from instance1 or instance2(first time) it is consuming on that instance only, but when I am sending message from the second instance it is consumed by both;

Code in git: https://github.com/AratRana/ApacheActiveMQ

Could you point me where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I am able to do it. When I started the consumer during server startup then I am able to see the message consumer in all instances. So to achieve this the consumers needs to be started before publishing any message.