# Cannot publish Topic-message to two subscriber simlutaneously using ActiveMQ

Tags: spring-boot, activemq-classic

I have referred to the [SpringBoot application publish and read from ActiveMQ topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41630436/springboot-application-publish-and-read-from-activemq-topic) to, publish a Topic using ActiveMQ. I have created two receiver micro-services which reads message from the topic.I have also created rest endpoint to publish the Topic.However, I have to execute this rest end point two times to publish the message for two receivers 
1). The first execution of rest endpoint will send message to Receiver1 
2). The second execution of rest endpoint will send message to Receiver2

Hence 2 receivers could not read from the Topic simultaneously.
Here is my code.

**PublisherApplication.java**

```java
package com.springboot;

//import statements

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableJms
public class PublisherApplication {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();      
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        //setPubSubDomain identifies Topic in ActiveMQ
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return factory;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        SpringApplication.run(PublisherApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();

    }

}
```

**PublishMessage.java**
[Rest-end point to publish Topic]

```java
package com.springboot.controller;

//import statements

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/schoolDashboard/topic")
class PublishMessage {

    public static final String MAILBOX_TOPIC = "mailbox.topic";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @GetMapping(path = "/sendEmail")
    public void sendStudentById() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Anindya-TopicSendMessage.java :: Publishing Email sent....");
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(MAILBOX_TOPIC, "Topic - Email Sent");
    }

}
```

**ReceiverApplication01**
[Note - Receiver01 is first microservice]

```java
package com.springboot;

//import statements

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class ReceiverApplication01 {


    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();      
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        //setPubSubDomain identifies Topic in ActiveMQ
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReceiverApplication01.class, args);
    }

}
```

**TopicMesssgeReceiver01.java**
[Receiver01 Read message from Topic]

```java
package com.springboot.message;

//import statement

@Component
public class TopicMesssgeReceiver01 {

    private final SimpleMessageConverter converter = new SimpleMessageConverter();

    public static final String MAILBOX_TOPIC = "mailbox.topic";

    @JmsListener(destination = MAILBOX_TOPIC, containerFactory = "topicListenerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(final Message message) throws JMSException{
        System.out.println("Receiver01 <" + String.valueOf(this.converter.fromMessage(message)) + ">");
    }

}
```

**ReceiverApplication02**
[Note:-Receiver02 is second microservice]

```java
package com.springboot;

//import statement

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class ReaderApplication02 {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);       
        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReaderApplication02.class, args);
    }

}
```

**TopicMesssgeReceiver02**
[Receiver02 Read message from Topic]

```java
package com.springboot.message;

//import statement

@Component
public class TopicMesssgeReceiver02 {


private final SimpleMessageConverter converter = new SimpleMessageConverter();

    public static final String MAILBOX_TOPIC = "mailbox.topic";

    @JmsListener(destination = MAILBOX_TOPIC, containerFactory = "topicListenerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(final Message message) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Receiver02 <" + String.valueOf(this.converter.fromMessage(message)) + ">");
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I think it is worth having a look at this similar problem discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52951752/message-is-not-consumed-by-all-consumers-when-network-brokers-is-configured-in-a?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Naveen!! Finally, I am able to do it. 
We have to set only *setPubSubDomain(true);* and spring-boot will take care all boiler-plate code. 
Now, two receiver Microservices can read message from Topic simultaneously 
Following are the code changes

**PublishMessage.java**
[Rest-end point to publish Topic]

```java
package com.springboot.controller;

//import statements

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/schoolDashboard/topic")
class PublishMessage {

    public static final String MAILBOX_TOPIC = "mailbox.topic";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

    @GetMapping(path = "/sendEmail")
    public void sendStudentById() throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Publisher :: Message sent...");
        /* Added this statement. setPubSubDomain(true) identifies Topic in ActiveMQ */
        jmsTemplate.setPubSubDomain(true);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(MAILBOX_TOPIC, "Topic - Email Sent");
    }

}
```

**ReceiverApplication02**
[Note:-Receiver02 is second microservice]

```java
package com.springboot;

//import statement

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class ReaderApplication02 {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> topicListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
            DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();       
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);    
        /* setPubSubDomain(true) should be placed after 
         * configuration of the specified jms listener container factory*/
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        return factory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReaderApplication02.class, args);
    }

}
```